# Cannot Open Database Created with Access 2007 in Access 2010 stack overflow error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, stack-overflow

I created an access database linked to a MS SQL 2008 Back end.  Whenever the user attempts to use this database in an Access 2010 machine the error dialog that appears reads:

> Run Time Error (28)
>   Out of stack space

The only options available in the dialog box are END, DEBUG and HELP.
END does nothing, DEBUG takes you to the opening code.

Tried the following:

1- Made the network folder a trusted location            SAME ERROR

2- Disabled all security checks on the trust center      SAME ERROR

3- Moved the file to the Desktop opened with shift and tried to compact and repair       SAME ERROR

4- Created a New database with format MDB and Copied all Objects error disappears but loses attachment, and email functionality.

In Summary:

I get error code when opening accdb file created in 2007 in any machine with Access 2010 either local or from the network and the problem is solved if I use MDB but I lose significant functionality.

Comment: Tried to downgrade the database to mdb format but got a whole different set of errors

Comment: How are you connecting to your SQL Server backend?  Are you using an Access Data Project (ADP) or ODBC?